# Hybrid ASP.NET/MVC application on IIS 7.5 .aspx pages not loading

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-3.0, iis-7.5

I have a hybrid ASP.NET/MVC 2 application that is currently hosted on II6.
I need to migrate this to IIS 7.5 and I'm having trouble getting it to work.

The furthest I've got is when the app pool is in integration mode, I migrated the web.congig using AppCmd.exe but only the MVC part worked and the .aspx pages wouldn't load.

I suspect that this is due to a custom handler that somone wrote called StaticFileHandler.
I know that this code is being hit as I see it in the log file.
And also checking the IISLogs I can see that the request returns a 200 http code

I've search around for answers but the only one I found that came close was someone who had their .aspx pages working and not their MVC part.

Has anyone got an idea what I can try?
I've been looking into this for days and havn't come up anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.
The issue was due to modules in the website.
These were doing things like compression and such, once taken them out, and removing them from the web.config, I got it working rather easily.